# Endpoints.MapControllerRoute pattern meaning

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

What is the use of assigning controller name and action name in the pattern like this

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name:"default",
                pattern: "{controller=home}/{action=index}/{id?}"
                );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pattern like

```
"{controller=home}/{action=index}/{id?}"
```

tells ASP.NET Core that if a URL ends with a path `/MyController/MyAction/MyId123`, it should dispatch the request to the method `MyAction` inside the controller `MyController`. That method could look like:

```cs
public class MyController {
    public IActionResult MyAction(string id) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now, by adding `=home` and `=index`, you give it a default value, and effectively matching all requests that don't map to an existing controller & action to `HomeController:Index` method.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#set-up-conventional-route):

> The route template `"{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"`:
>
> - Matches a URL path like `/Products/Details/5`
> - Extracts the route values `{ controller = Products, action = Details, id = 5 }` by tokenizing the path. The extraction of route values
>   results in a match if the app has a controller named
>   `ProductsController` and a `Details` action:
>
>   ```cs
>   public class ProductsController : Controller {
>       public IActionResult Details(int id)
>       {
>           return ControllerContext.MyDisplayRouteInfo(id);
>       } 
>   }
>   ```
> - `{controller=Home}` defines `Home` as the default controller.
> - `{action=Index}` defines `Index` as the default action.
> - The `?` character in `{id?}` defines `id` as optional.